# How to get the number after certain slash faster in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

In this link, I want to get `302621221479` from the url, Can I do it **faster**?

I am asking for learning how to improve my code not how to do it.

```
url = 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/Deep-V-Neck-Sequin-Bodycon-Cocktail-Dress-Women-Clubwear-Sexy-Party-Dress-/302621221479?var=&hash=item8c09eb2518'

u = url.split('/')

id_product = u[-1].split('?')

print(id_product[0])
```

Comment: If you want to parse a URL, maybe use [`urllib.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse)? But I doubt this part of your code is really a limiting factor.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
URL = 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/Deep-V-Neck-Sequin-Bodycon-Cocktail-Dress-Women-Clubwear-Sexy-Party-Dress-/302621221479?var=&hash=item8c09eb2518'

product_id = URL.split("/")[-1].split('?')[0] ##you can try like this
product_id = URL.split('?')[0].split("/")[-1]  ##this one is safer
print(product_id)
```

Output:

```
302621221479
```